# Foreach in get_post_types to apply a different filter per post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have a class in my plugin with the following function:

```
protected function get_post_types($output='names') {
    if (! is_array($post_types = get_post_types(array( 'show_ui' => true ), $output)))
        return array();

    // WE CAN DISABLE HERE THE MEDIA POST TYPE
    unset($post_types['attachment']);
    return $post_types;
}
```

And this other function which executes a tweak for WordPress, in this case for removing the bulk actions per post type.

```
function tweak()
{
    foreach( $this->get_post_types() as $type => $data) {
        if($this->setting('disable_bulk_' . $type))
        {
            add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-' . $type, '__return_empty_array');
        }
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly for pages, posts and attachments (if I don't unset this last one) post types, but not for other CPTs (it is working only with the built in CPTs, but I am not passing the builtin true as an argument).

Here is the full class:

```
class My_Tweaks_Component_Content_Bulk_Actions_Removal extends My_Tweaks_Component {
    //Set Component's Environment Type
    function env()
    {
        return 'admin';
    }

    protected function get_post_types($output='names') {
        if (! is_array($post_types = get_post_types(array( 'show_ui' => true ), $output)))
            return array();

        // WE CAN DISABLE HERE THE MEDIA POST TYPE
        unset($post_types['attachment']);
        return $post_types;
    }

    // Set Component's Fields
    public function fields()
    {
        // Empty array of fields
        $fields = array();

        // Add every field
        $fields[] = array(
            'name' => $this->name('enabled'),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __('Enable this option?', POMTWEAKS_SLUG),
            'description' => __('Remove the bulk actions from posts, pages and custom post types listings in admin.', POMTWEAKS_SLUG),
        );
        $fields[] = array(
            'name' => $this->name('separator'),
            'type' => 'separator',
        );

        foreach( $this->get_post_types() as $type => $data)
        {

            $postTypeObject = get_post_type_object($type);

            $fields[] = array(
                'name' => $this->name('disable_bulk_' . $type),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'label' => sprintf( esc_html__( 'Disable bulk actions for %s?', POMTWEAKS_SLUG ), __( $postTypeObject->labels->name ) ),
                'description' => null,
            );

        }

        return $fields;
    }

    // Check if the component has a value that determines if the tweak has to be executed
    public function is_active()
    {
        $this->settings = $this->all_fields();
        if ($this->setting('enabled')) $this->disabled = false;
        return $this;
    }

    // Set When the Component must be Executed
    function run()
    {
        if($this->setting('enabled'))
        {
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'tweak'));
        }
    }

    // Remove the bulk actions from posts, pages and custom post types listings in admin.
    function tweak()
    {
        foreach( $this->get_post_types() as $type => $data) {
            if($this->setting('disable_bulk_' . $type))
            {
                add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-' . $type, '__return_empty_array');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has any clue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: please complete your code, how your class called, how and where you call `function tweak()`, and how `$this->setting('disable_bulk_' . $type)` work?

Comment: and make sure you use hook `admin_init`

Comment: Hi @Jevuska, thanks a lot for your answer. I edited my question and added the full class so you can see all the stuff happening there. I was already using the admin_init hook. Thanks again!

Comment: where is $this->setting() function? how about is_active, where is you call this function?

Comment: Hi @Jevuska, thanks again. That functions are in a file from the core of a framework that was not coded by me nor my mates. is_active only checks that the first option has a true value and then continues by executing the tweak with the run function...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack exchange :)

Some other plugin ( or your plugin elsewhere ) may be getting executed later, and maybe adding some elements to the array.

Try to give your hook a higher priority, replacing your `tweak` method with following...

```
function tweak()
{
    foreach( $this->get_post_types('objects') as $type => $data) {
        if($this->setting('disable_bulk_' . $type))
        {
            if ( ! empty( $data->rewrite['slug'] ) ) {
                $type = $data->rewrite['slug'];
            }
            add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-' . $type, '__return_empty_array',999);
        }
    }
}
```

This should delay the execution you function.
Lemme know if that helps :)

Cheers

----------------EDIT------------------------

Gets post type `objects` instead of default labels.
Uses slug instead of post type name when slug is defined ( and not empty ) in post type object.

Comment: Hello @Shramee Srivastav, thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately it did not work. I even tried with PHP_INT_MAX instead of 999 but no luck.

I also checked the codex and saw that the priority should go before the args, but anyway it didn't work.

It is really weird...

Comment: Fun fact is that if I replace the $type by the slug of the CPT (e.g. 'articles') it works. If I echo $type (for example in the admin_notices hook) it displays properly the slugs of all CPTs.

Comment: Hi G. Oronez,
Edited my answer to use post type slugs whenever available.
Some plugins may use a different slug then the post type name so it gets a bit tricky.

Comment: Hello, once more, many thanks, but I got no luck with that. I also tried to change the get_post_types function to return objects instead of names and then get the slug, but it did not work... I will keep digging!